# How to get the first column data of a row that is selected on document load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I would like to find the first column's data for a specific row that is selected on `onload` of the document.

How can I get that first `td` element value using jQuery?

I tried something like this, but this is not working.

```
var id = $('#s_1_l tr(:"selected")').find("td:eq(1)").text();
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: you mean the first tr element?

Comment: not really..I meant whichever tr row is selected on document load..doesn't matter whether its first or last or whatever.

Comment: You can use :selected for tr

Comment: how do you select a <tr> in html or java?

Comment: @Oyeme but how to select that?

Comment: @Oyeme Can you please give me the correct syntax? I tried with that, but I guess sysntax was not correct as I mentioned above.

Comment: It depends on how you select a row.You can add a marker or something just for your row.For example it could be a class .selected

Comment: I tried with this code and it returns all the 1st td element values that are not selected. The code is



alert($('#s_1_l tr:not(:selected)').find("td:eq(1)").text());

But when I used this code it returns a blank alert box..



alert($('#s_1_l tr(:selected)').find("td:eq(1)").text());

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you mark selected TRs. Assuming your html is

```
<table>
    <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr selected="selected"><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td></tr>
</table>
```

Your selector would be: `$('tr[selected="selected"]').css('color', 'red');`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S2rvR/

Comment: BTW, this is the "attribute equals" selector, see http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Check this it may help

```
 $('tr[selected="selected"] td:first-child' ).css('color', 'red');
```

JS fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/S2rvR/1/)